# Download file in NativeScript Angular for iOS

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am the one who develop mobile app by using NativeScript with Angular. Now I can't find the proper way to download file in iOS in gallery. If you have some experiences with that, please share me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick a file from gallery, use the [mediapicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-mediafilepicker) plugin which will launch the gallery and allow your user to pick images. On the success callback you will have access to seleected image(s).

Comment: Hi Manoj, I want to download file in gallery for iOS. I don't want to pick up a file from gallery.

Comment: What you mean by download? Do you mean you want to save something **to** gallery?

Comment: Sure, that is what I want. If you have some experiences with that please share me or redirect me the link.

Comment: What is your source for image, if it's camera then you already have `saveToGallery` flag in camera plugin. In case if you have downloaded image and want it to appear in gallery, then you may use the same code from the plugin and use your file instead. For iOS: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/44d7f13bb4b008c39f987d569ecf5f8862cfbee7/src/camera.ios.ts#L54 and Android: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/44d7f13bb4b008c39f987d569ecf5f8862cfbee7/src/camera.android.ts#L98-L113

Comment: Hi Manoj, the image is from url something like 'https://file.somedomain.com/myResources/image.png'. Thanks.

Comment: Simply download the file and use the same methods mentioned above by passing that path.